# Manual modification Table of contents in Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, margins

I am having trouble in making table of contents using `\tableofcontents` command.Here is my long latex file.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section*{\Huge Chapter 1}
    \section*{\Large Symmetries in Classical Physics} 
    \subsection*{Introduction}
    Symmetries plays an important role in the fields of phsyics.
    \subsection{Mechanics of many particle System}
    Let us consider a system of more than 2 particles such that
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The external forces applied on the particles be say $F^{(ext)}_{i}$ and
    \item Forces applied by the system i.e. the interaction force be $F^{j}_{i}$
        \end{itemize}
    $\therefore$ From Newtons 2nd Law of motion, we can write\\
    \begin{equation}
    m_ia_i=\dot{p_i}=F^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}, i=1,2,...N
    \end{equation}
    Where 'i' stands for denoting the particle and\\
    $F_{i}^{ext}$ stands for  external force acting on $i^{th}$ particle and\\
    $F^{j}_{i}$ is the interaction force acting on the $i^{th}$ particle due to all other paricle (i.e j particle).\\
    So $\therefore$ for N particles one can write it as \\
    \begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i \ne j}^{N}F^{j}_{i} ,where F_{i}^{i}=0.\end{equation*}
From Newtons 3rd law,one can write forces due to internal/interaction force as\\
\begin{equation}
F_{i}^{j}=-F_{j}^{i}.
\end{equation}
\section*{\large \boldmath Important points to be noted:}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Interacyion force is only possible iff there are more than on particles and bheave as an central force.
    \item Ad they occur in pair, forces among themselves are neglected.
\end{itemize}
For a closed system,where one knows that linear momentum is conserved i.e.external force acting on the system is zero.\\
$\implies$ A closed system can be reffered to as a inertial frame.\\
$\therefore$ From eq.(1) we have,\\
\begin{equation*}
\sum_i\dot{p_i}=\frac{d^2}{ dt^2}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\sum_iF^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\sum_{i}F_{i}^{ext}  
\end{equation*} where we have used eqn.(2).
\newpage
This is because \\
    As \begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}=\sum_{i \ne j}F^{i}_{j}
    \end{equation*}
    \begin{equation*}
    =\frac{1}{2}[\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{i}_{j}]=0 \text{(used dummy variable conncept)}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\implies\sum_{i}\dot{p_i} =  F^{(ext)}_{i}
    \end{equation}
To understand the physical significance of eqn.(1),using the concept of center of mass for many particles we have,\\
\begin{center}
    \begin{equation}
    \boldmath {R}=\frac{\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}}{\sum_{i}m_{i}} 
        \end{equation}
        \end{center}
where M=$\sum_{i} m_{i}$ is the total mass of the system.\\
$\therefore$ eqn.(3) become,\\
\begin{equation}
M\frac{d^2R}{dt^2} = \sum_{i}F_{i}^{ext}=F^{ext}
\end{equation}
 \begin{equation*}\textbf{P}=\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=M\dot{\textbf{R}}
\end{equation*}
\section*{Conservation Laws}
\subsection{Linear momentum}
Frome eqn.(5) we have\\
\begin{equation*}\textbf{P}=\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=\frac{d}{dt}\sum_{i} m_{i}r_{i}=M\dot{\textbf{R}}
\end{equation*}
\textbf{Important points}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Applying the external force on the entire mass of the system, the C.O.M move along too.
    \item If $F^{ext}$=0,then the total linear momentum is conserved.\\
    i.e $\frac{d\textbf{P}}{dt}$=0 $\implies$ $\textbf{P}$=constant of motion.\\
    $\implies$ C.O.M moves with cobstant/uniform velocity without the extrnal force.\\ 
\end{itemize}
We can relate this scenario by the radioactive decay nucleus disintegrating ejects different particles which move in different direction in such a way that C.O.M moves along with constant velocity after disnitegration.\\
\subsection{Conservation of angular momentum}
Angular momentum for the system of particles is written as:-\\
\begin{equation*}
    \textbf{L}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times p_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=\sum_{i}(r_{i} \times \dot{p_{i}}+\dot{r_{i}} \times p_{i})
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times \dot{p_{i}}  (\because \dot{r_{i}} \times p_{i}=0)
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\dot{\textbf{L}}=r_{i} \times(\sum_{i}F^(ext)_i)+\sum_{i \ne j} F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\dot{L}}{dt}=\sum_{i}r_{i} \times F^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}r_{i} \times F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation}
where 1st term represnts total torque due to external forces and 2nd term represents total torque due to internal forces.\\
Now one can easily prove that 2nd term in eqn.(6) is zero.\\
\textbf{Proof}:-Let $N_{i}$ be the sum of all internal torque acting on the system i.e.,\\
\begin{equation*} N_{i}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}=\sum_{i\ne j} r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j} \text{()used dummy varialble concept} \end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
N_{i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i \ne j} [ r_{i} \times F_{i}^{j}+ r_{j} \times F_{i}^{j}]
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\text{Now as}  F_{i}^{j}= -F_{j}^{i}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
N_{i}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i \ne j}  (r_{i}-r_{j}) \times F_{i}^{j}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
r_{ij}=r_{i}-r_{j}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\implies N_{int}=\frac{1}{2} \times r_{ij} \times F^{j}_{i}
\end{equation*}
From the figure below one can see that $r_{ij} \times F^{j}_{i}$=0; $\because$ $r_{ij}$ of particle $i^{th}$ and $j^{th}$ are parallel to the line of action of $F^{j}_{i}$.
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{IMG_20200426_202229}
    \caption*{Representation of $i_{th}$ and $j_{th}$ particles }
    \label{fig:img20200426202229}
\end{figure}
\begin{equation*}
\implies\bf{ \frac{dL}{dt}=\sum_{i} r_{i} \times F_{i}^{ext}=N^{ext}}=\text{Sum of external torques}
\end{equation*}
Now if $N^{ext}$=0 $\implies$ \text{\textbf{'L'} is aconstant of motion and thus angular momentum is conserved}.
\subsection{Conservation of Energy} 



    \end{document}
```

As far i know the section command automatically adds the title in table of contents but where as for `\section*{}` i saw it doesn't include those and also as i made section in many pages making it bold and large in the table of content also it goes big but i want that to manually make it modify.Anyone on this can help (and also when i preview it in pdf i see my whole written text and like centered and doesn't consume whole page maybe due to default margin issue).

Comment: Welcome! Sorry to say this, but if you inappropriately use basic LaTeX commands, it is very hard to get what one wants.  `\section*{\Huge Chapter 1}` is not quite the intended use.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat can you help modify it out for me would be really helpful for me as i am new to it and dont know the exact basics of it.It would be kind of you if you can set up for me so that i can learn it now and dont do mistakes in future.

Comment: It is unfortunately not so easy since I do not really understand what you want to achieve. If you want chapters, the `article` class is not what you need. You should never add these formatting commands in `\section`, but use e.g. `titlesec` to change the formatting. Since you only use `\subsection{...}` but not `\section{...}` the entries of the table of contents are of the form `0.1 ...`.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat if you could do the possible changes and make it write as i totally confused on what things to do and what not.Would really appreciate if you help me as i am just a beginner.Really need help on this as it would clarify most of the latex skills by making changes to all or some bit.Thank you

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you are trying to do.  As a general rule, you shouldn't be telling TeX `\Huge`, `\Large`, or `Chapter`.  The primary point of `\section*` is that it doesn't end up in the table of contents, so if you're wanting it to end up in the table of contents, then the question is why aren't you using `\section`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are using the `article` class and trying to fake `\chapter` divisions.

However, to get your `\section*{text}` inserted into the ToC do:

```
\section*{Section title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section title}
```

and similarly for subsections `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subsection title}` etc.

Note that your divisional numbering scheme is 0.n.

It might be a lot of work but I suggest that you use a class that provides chapters such as `book`, `report`, `memoir` (a superset of `book` and `report`)  and other such classes. Below is the possible start of a revision of your code.

```
% sectocprob.tex  SE 543098 section* in ToC
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
%    \newpage
%    \section*{\Huge Chapter 1}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Chapter 1}
    \chapter{Large Symmetries in Classical Physics}
%    \section*{\Large Symmetries in Classical Physics} 
%    \subsection*{Introduction}
    \section{Introduction}
    Symmetries plays an important role in the fields of phsyics.
%    \subsection{Mechanics of many particle System}
    \section{Mechanics of many particle System}
    Let us consider a system of more than 2 particles such that
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The external forces applied on the particles be say $F^{(ext)}_{i}$ and
    \item Forces applied by the system i.e. the interaction force be $F^{j}_{i}$
        \end{itemize}
    $\therefore$ From Newtons 2nd Law of motion, we can write\\
    \begin{equation}
    m_ia_i=\dot{p_i}=F^{(ext)}_{i}+\sum_{i \ne j}F^{j}_{i}, i=1,2,...N
    \end{equation}
    Where 'i' stands for denoting the particle and\\
    $F_{i}^{ext}$ stands for  external force acting on $i^{th}$ particle and\\
    $F^{j}_{i}$ is the interaction force acting on the $i^{th}$ particle due to all other paricle (i.e j particle).\\
    So $\therefore$ for N particles one can write it as \\
    \begin{equation*}
    \sum_{i \ne j}^{N}F^{j}_{i} ,where F_{i}^{i}=0.\end{equation*}
From Newtons 3rd law,one can write forces due to internal/interaction force as\\
\begin{equation}
F_{i}^{j}=-F_{j}^{i}.
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Try the above to see if it approaches what you want (which I am very unclear about).